# application order in GAP multiplication

Tags: gap

GAP multiplication of permutations $p1 * p2$ first applies $p1$, then applies $p2$ to the result.  Many textbooks apply $p2$, then apply $p1$ to the result, which feels more consistent with composition of functions, so the action on set element $x$ would be $p1(p2(x))$.  Is there a way to configure GAP multiplication to behave this way?

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot configure it differently, and there is no way one could add such functionality without rewriting the system from scratch.

The reason GAP (and much of group-theoretic literature) uses this way of multiplication as it is most natural for actions on the right and the exponential notation for actions $\omega^g$, which saves on unneccessary parentheses.
Then clearly one would want that $\omega^{gh}=(\omega^g)^h$.